# Compare table fields for each row data and take some action (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, row

Well, I have a table called "amigos" with 28 fields (id, number, fecharev. horarev, etc).

I want to compare a few fields and make and action if the fields are different:

So I have this code to compare the fields:

```
 $c = mysql_pconnect('localhost','root','eagle');

mysql_select_db('controlj_amigos');
 $bit1 = mysql_query("SELECT tamano FROM amigos WHERE id=$id", $c);
 $bit2 = mysql_query("SELECT tamano2 FROM amigos WHERE id=$id", $c);

 $tama1 = mysql_fetch_object($bit1);
$tama2 = mysql_fetch_object($bit2);
$curDate = date("Y-m-d");



$bit11 = mysql_query("SELECT date_actual FROM amigos WHERE id=$id", $c);
$bit12 = mysql_query("SELECT fecharev FROM amigos WHERE id=$id", $c);
$fec1 = mysql_fetch_object($bit11);
$fec2 = mysql_fetch_object($bit12);
```

Also I this code that compare and take some action:

```
  if ($tama1->tamano < $tama2->tamano2 && $fec1->date_actual > $fec2->fecharev)  
    {  

  $query_auto = "UPDATE amigos set fecharev=CURDATE(),horarev=CURTIME(),ince='1' where 
    }
```

So, I want that for each row of my table (amigos) just made the comparison ("if ($tama1->tamano < $tama2->tamano2 && $fec1->date_actual > $fec2->fecharev)
    {  ") and ejecute the condition but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of while loop so that each row in the field will get compared...

Make use of flag variable...

When the condition will become true...set the flag variable to certain value..and use break...

Outside the while loop...check the flag and fire your update query which you have fired at last...